# CUDA installation still doesn't resolve Kernel has died error in ipynb

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to run a CNN for Image Recognition in Jupyter Notebook and when I fit the model to the training and test set the Kernel crashes. My dataset consists of 700 images. I use Tensorflow 2.10 and recently I have installed CUDA 11.2 and Cdnn 8.1, but the error still persists, even though the installation of CUDA was performed well: I copied the files from the zip to the Nvidia Toolkit folder in Program Files and added the required paths to Environment Variables. However, this print statement `print(len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))` returned 0, indicating maybe that the GPU isn't working accordingly.
This is the Jupyter log:

```
02:53:33.022 [info] User belongs to experiment group 'FastKernelPicker'
02:53:33.023 [info] User belongs to experiment group 'NewRemoteUriStorage'
02:53:33.023 [info] User belongs to experiment group 'PasswordManager'
02:53:33.023 [info] User belongs to experiment group 'NewJupyterSession'
02:53:33.739 [info] Start refreshing Kernel Picker (1691711613739)
02:53:33.748 [info] Using Pylance
02:53:36.825 [info] Starting Kernel startUsingPythonInterpreter, .jvsc74a57bd00550fd4970c8104f10a40c40c7929f64f2ec61f8d313e3cfcf83ee641623eae2.c:\Users\<username>\anaconda3\envs\DataScience\python.exe.c:\Users\<username>\anaconda3\envs\DataScience\python.exe.-m#ipykernel_launcher  (Python Path: ~\anaconda3\envs\DataScience\python.exe, Conda, DataScience, 3.10.11) for '~\Desktop\Machine Learning A-Z (Codes and Datasets)\Part 8 - Deep Learning\Section 40 - Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN)\Python\CNN_with_observations.ipynb' (disableUI=true)
02:53:38.644 [info] End refreshing Kernel Picker (1691711613739)
02:53:44.812 [info] Handle Execution of Cells 2,3,4,8,10,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,28,30,32,33 for ~\Desktop\Machine Learning A-Z (Codes and Datasets)\Part 8 - Deep Learning\Section 40 - Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN)\Python\CNN_with_observations.ipynb
02:53:45.263 [warn] Failed to get activated env vars for ~\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.10.exe in 10698ms
02:53:45.306 [info] Process Execution: ~\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.10.exe -c "import site;print("USER_BASE_VALUE");print(site.USER_SITE);print("USER_BASE_VALUE");"
02:53:45.560 [info] Process Execution: ~\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.10.exe -m pip list
02:53:53.059 [info] Process Execution: ~\anaconda3\envs\DataScience\python.exe -c "import ipykernel; print(ipykernel.__version__); print("5dc3a68c-e34e-4080-9c3e-2a532b2ccb4d"); print(ipykernel.__file__)"
02:53:53.071 [info] Process Execution: ~\anaconda3\envs\DataScience\python.exe c:\Users\<username>\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.7.1002162226-win32-x64\pythonFiles\vscode_datascience_helpers\kernel_interrupt_daemon.py --ppid 5360
    > cwd: ~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.7.1002162226-win32-x64\pythonFiles\vscode_datascience_helpers
02:53:53.085 [info] Process Execution: ~\anaconda3\envs\DataScience\python.exe -m pip list
02:53:53.403 [info] Process Execution: ~\anaconda3\envs\DataScience\python.exe -m ipykernel_launcher --ip=127.0.0.1 --stdin=9003 --control=9001 --hb=9000 --Session.signature_scheme="hmac-sha256" --Session.key=b"ad2f8ce2-f23e-4db0-8a4d-a624315f236b" --shell=9002 --transport="tcp" --iopub=9004 --f=c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v2-5360UzFAFcMGdKaa.json
    > cwd: ~\Desktop\Machine Learning A-Z (Codes and Datasets)\Part 8 - Deep Learning\Section 40 - Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN)\Python
02:53:54.170 [info] ipykernel version & path 6.25.0, ~\anaconda3\envs\DataScience\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py for ~\anaconda3\envs\DataScience\python.exe
02:53:56.017 [info] Started Kernel DataScience (Python 3.10.11) (pid: 16644)
02:53:56.017 [info] Started new session 3eb01e69-3836-4e80-97dd-6623022039e5
02:53:56.207 [info] Process Execution: ~\anaconda3\envs\DataScience\python.exe c:\Users\<username>\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.7.1002162226-win32-x64\pythonFiles\printJupyterDataDir.py
02:53:56.234 [info] Kernel acknowledged execution of cell 2 @ 1691711636222
02:53:56.334 [warn] Got a non-existent Jupyer Data Dir file:///c%3A/Users/<username>/AppData/Roaming/Python/share/jupyter
02:54:05.615 [info] End cell 2 execution @ 1691711645610, started @ 1691711636222, elapsed time = 9.388s
02:54:05.622 [info] Kernel acknowledged execution of cell 3 @ 1691711645617
02:54:05.645 [info] End cell 3 execution @ 1691711645641, started @ 1691711645617, elapsed time = 0.024s
02:54:05.652 [info] Kernel acknowledged execution of cell 4 @ 1691711645647
02:54:05.661 [info] End cell 4 execution @ 1691711645656, started @ 1691711645647, elapsed time = 0.009s
02:54:05.665 [info] Kernel acknowledged execution of cell 8 @ 1691711645663
02:54:05.771 [info] End cell 8 execution @ 1691711645767, started @ 1691711645663, elapsed time = 0.104s
02:54:05.780 [info] Kernel acknowledged execution of cell 10 @ 1691711645773
02:54:05.818 [info] End cell 10 execution @ 1691711645815, started @ 1691711645773, elapsed time = 0.042s
02:54:05.824 [info] Kernel acknowledged execution of cell 13 @ 1691711645820
02:54:05.856 [warn] StdErr from Kernel Process 2023-08-11 02:54:05.
02:54:05.856 [warn] StdErr from Kernel Process 855760: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in ot
02:54:05.857 [warn] StdErr from Kernel Process her operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
02:54:05.866 [warn] StdErr from Kernel Process 2023-08-11 02:54:05.865805: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:146] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
02:54:06.039 [info] End cell 13 execution @ 1691711646036, started @ 1691711645820, elapsed time = 0.216s
02:54:06.069 [info] Kernel acknowledged execution of cell 15 @ 1691711646042
02:54:06.184 [info] End cell 15 execution @ 1691711646179, started @ 1691711646042, elapsed time = 0.137s
02:54:06.191 [info] Kernel acknowledged execution of cell 17 @ 1691711646186
02:54:06.215 [info] End cell 17 execution @ 1691711646211, started @ 1691711646186, elapsed time = 0.025s
02:54:06.223 [info] Kernel acknowledged execution of cell 19 @ 1691711646216
02:54:06.278 [info] End cell 19 execution @ 1691711646274, started @ 1691711646216, elapsed time = 0.058s
02:54:06.286 [info] Kernel acknowledged execution of cell 21 @ 1691711646280
02:54:06.307 [info] End cell 21 execution @ 1691711646304, started @ 1691711646280, elapsed time = 0.024s
02:54:06.313 [info] Kernel acknowledged execution of cell 23 @ 1691711646309
02:54:06.371 [info] End cell 23 execution @ 1691711646368, started @ 1691711646309, elapsed time = 0.059s
02:54:06.384 [info] Kernel acknowledged execution of cell 25 @ 1691711646373
02:54:06.419 [info] End cell 25 execution @ 1691711646416, started @ 1691711646373, elapsed time = 0.043s
02:54:06.430 [info] Kernel acknowledged execution of cell 28 @ 1691711646421
02:54:06.451 [info] End cell 28 execution @ 1691711646446, started @ 1691711646421, elapsed time = 0.025s
02:54:06.457 [info] Kernel acknowledged execution of cell 30 @ 1691711646452
02:54:06.573 [warn] StdErr from Kernel Process OMP: Error #15: Initializing libiomp5md.dll, but found libiomp5 already initialized.
OMP: Hint This means that multiple copies of the OpenMP runtime have been linked into the program. That is dangerous, since it can degrade performance or cause incorrect results. The best thing to do is to ensure that only a single OpenMP runtime is linked into the process, e.g. by avoiding static linking of the OpenMP runtime in any library. As an unsafe, unsupported, undocumented workaround you can set the environment variable KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=TRUE to allow the program to continue to execute, but that may cause crashes or silently produce incorrect results. For more information, please see http://www.intel.com/software/products/support/.
02:54:07.217 [error] Disposing session as kernel process died ExitCode: 3, Reason: 2023-08-11 02:54:05.855760: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-08-11 02:54:05.865805: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:146] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
OMP: Error #15: Initializing libiomp5md.dll, but found libiomp5 already initialized.
OMP: Hint This means that multiple copies of the OpenMP runtime have been linked into the program. That is dangerous, since it can degrade performance or cause incorrect results. The best thing to do is to ensure that only a single OpenMP runtime is linked into the process, e.g. by avoiding static linking of the OpenMP runtime in any library. As an unsafe, unsupported, undocumented workaround you can set the environment variable KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=TRUE to allow the program to continue to execute, but that may cause crashes or silently produce incorrect results. For more information, please see http://www.intel.com/software/products/support/.

02:54:07.218 [info] Dispose Kernel process 16644.
02:54:07.218 [error] Raw kernel process exited code: 3
02:54:07.220 [error] Error in waiting for cell to complete Error: Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
    at t.KernelShellFutureHandler.dispose (c:\Users\<username>\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.7.1002162226-win32-x64\out\extension.node.js:2:32375)
    at c:\Users\<username>\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.7.1002162226-win32-x64\out\extension.node.js:2:51427
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at y._clearKernelState (c:\Users\<username>\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.7.1002162226-win32-x64\out\extension.node.js:2:51412)
    at y.dispose (c:\Users\<username>\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.7.1002162226-win32-x64\out\extension.node.js:2:44894)
    at c:\Users\<username>\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.7.1002162226-win32-x64\out\extension.node.js:24:114648
    at ae (c:\Users\<username>\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.7.1002162226-win32-x64\out\extension.node.js:2:1588852)
    at rv.dispose (c:\Users\<username>\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.7.1002162226-win32-x64\out\extension.node.js:24:114624)
    at sv.dispose (c:\Users\<username>\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.7.1002162226-win32-x64\out\extension.node.js:24:117994)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
02:54:07.222 [warn] Cell completed with errors {
  message: 'Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done'
}
02:54:07.223 [info] End cell 30 execution @ 1691711647223, started @ 1691711646452, elapsed time = 0.771s
02:54:07.224 [warn] Cancel all remaining cells due to cancellation or failure in execution
02:54:07.224 [info] End cell 32 execution @ undefined, started @ undefined, elapsed time = 0s
02:54:07.224 [info] End cell 33 execution @ undefined, started @ undefined, elapsed time = 0s
02:54:07.325 [info] End cell 30 execution @ undefined, started @ undefined, elapsed time = 0s
```

Comment: Found the problem from the log. It appears that `libiomp5md.dll` was duplicated. I ran the following `import os
os.environ["KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK"]="TRUE"` and it works. However this doesn't solve the GPU problem. I hope this does not affect the model accuracy.